# Is There Any Solution To Check In PDFKIT That All Fields Of Pdf Form Are Filled Or Not?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, pdfkit

Is there any way to find the current pdf content size.

For example:-

When user open the pdf file and fill some information in the pdf and click on submit button. Then how to check pdf content size means the content fill fully or not. If user not fully added the details, pending some TextFiled in the pdf, then we need to show alert "Please fill all the information."

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    setupNavigationBar()
    
    self.view.addSubview(pdfView)
    
    if let documentURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: pdfName, withExtension: "pdf") {
        if let document = PDFDocument(url: documentURL) {
           
            pdfView.autoScales = true
            pdfView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            document.delegate = self
            pdfView.document = document
           pdfView.autoScales = true
            pdfView.minScaleFactor = 1.5
            pdfView.maxScaleFactor = 5 }}
```

Can someone please explain to me is it possible in swift if yes please guide me how to achieve this, I've tried lot of search but no results yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[Here the image of My pdf form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBeLT.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well this is programmatically way, declare your textfields and button Save:

```
let firstTextfield: UITextField = {
    let tf = UITextField()
    tf.placeholder = "First Textfield"
    tf.backgroundColor = .white
    tf.textColor = .black
    tf.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    
    return tf
}()

let secondTextfield: UITextField = {
    let tf = UITextField()
    tf.placeholder = "Second Textfield"
    tf.backgroundColor = .white
    tf.textColor = .black
    tf.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    
    return tf
}()

let thirdTextfield: UITextField = {
    let tf = UITextField()
    tf.placeholder = "Third Textfield"
    tf.backgroundColor = .white
    tf.textColor = .black
    tf.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    
    return tf
}()

let saveDataButton: UIButton = {
    let b = UIButton()
    b.backgroundColor = .white
    b.setTitle("Save", for: .normal)
    b.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    b.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .semibold)
    b.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    b.clipsToBounds = true
    
    return b
}()
```

Now in viewDidLoad declare stackView and set constraints:

```
view.backgroundColor = .black
    
    saveDataButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(controlTextInTextfields), for: .touchUpInside) // call control function
    
    let staxkView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [firstTextfield, secondTextfield, thirdTextfield, saveDataButton])
    staxkView.axis = .vertical
    staxkView.distribution = .fillEqually
    staxkView.spacing = 6
    staxkView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    view.addSubview(staxkView)
    staxkView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    staxkView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    staxkView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    staxkView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 218).isActive = true // height of all textfields, button and space
```

After that write your control func:

```
@objc func controlTextInTextfields() {
    if firstTextfield.text == "" || secondTextfield.text == "" || thirdTextfield.text == "" {
        print("no text in one of Textfields!")
    } else {
        print("All TF contains text!")
    }
```

If you don't understand well, open new file and copy and paste my code

Comment: Sir,I want to edit Pdf Form Fields Not a TextFields. PdfForm Image  link in above.